# How do I properly decode the .bin files (RLE compression)? (DOS game - 1988)

Tags: ida, disassembly, binary-analysis, binary, disassemblers

Does anyone know what tools should I use to extract the backgrounds and sprites of this very rare old game: Armorik the Viking?

The files are in .BIN format. Compression is RLE

The game is from 1988 and was released by InfoGrames.

This is the game:

https://archive.org/download/msdos_Armorik_the_Viking_-_The_Eight_Conquests_1988/Armorik_the_Viking_-_The_Eight_Conquests_1988.zip

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Update:
Thanks to Max and Ali Rizvi-Santiago for their help, I lost access to the previous post so I will update it here with what I found so far and with some of your comments.

I tried through cpp to decode the file BACKS.BIN but I can only view one image inside the output_images.bin file generated. It looks like the output file does not contain all the content from the input file BACKS.BIN; I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas on how to improve the below code? Many thanks!
My viewer is GBS but that works only for uncompressed files.

here it is a view from the decoded output file of BACKS.BIN: - I can only see 1 image, how do i fix the cpp code?

[image: BACKS.BIN]

Some info for BACKS.BIN:

All images are 320x200, 2 bits per pixel.

all images contain header - 8 bytes (4 values - 2 bytes per value, all header contain values 0,0-319,199)

Images are interlaced - first part of image contains only even rows, second - odd rows.

All images are packed with RLE compression

[image: MOTIFS.BIN]         -IT WAS NOT COMPRESSED BY DEFAULT

MOTIFS.BIN - sprites. This file is not packed, so you can see/extract sprites with programs like "Texture/Tiles finder" (if they support CGA/2 bits per pixel modes).

256 sprites of size 32x32 pixels

3 sprites of size 48x48 pixels

3 sprites of size 64x64 pixels

2 bits per pixel, CGA pal.

After each sprite lies its transparency mask, also 2 bits per pixel. If 2 bits in mask both set then corresponding pixel in sprite is transparent.

C++ CODE TO GENERATE A DECODED COPY OF BACK.BIN(RLE COMPRESSION)
DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY: THE OUTPUT IS VERY SMALL SO IT DOES NOT DECOMPRESS THE INPUT FILE PROPERLY. Please help. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

const int IMAGE_WIDTH = 320;
const int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 200;
const int HEADER_SIZE = 8;

struct ImageHeader {
    int width;
    int height;
};

bool getNextTwoBytes(const std::vector<char>& data, int position, short& word) {
    if (position + 1 >= data.size())
        return false;

    word = (static_cast<uint8_t>(data[position + 1]) << 8) | static_cast<uint8_t>(data[position]);
    return true;
}

bool extractAndDecompressImages(const std::string& inputFilePath, const std::string& outputFilePath) {
    std::ifstream inputFile(inputFilePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!inputFile) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open input file.\n";
        return false;
    }

    inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streampos fileSize = inputFile.tellg();
    inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    int imageCount = static_cast<int>(fileSize / (HEADER_SIZE + IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    if (imageCount == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Invalid input file format.\n";
        return false;
    }

    std::ofstream outputFile(outputFilePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!outputFile) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not create output file " << outputFilePath << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; ++i) {
        ImageHeader header;
        inputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&header), sizeof(ImageHeader));

        std::vector<char> compressedData(IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        inputFile.read(compressedData.data(), compressedData.size());

        std::vector<char> decompressedData;
        decompressedData.reserve(IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT * 2); // Reserve enough space to avoid reallocations

        int position = 0;

        while (position < compressedData.size()) {
            unsigned char controlByte = static_cast<unsigned char>(compressedData[position++]);
            if (controlByte == 0) {
                break;
            } else if (controlByte == 0x80) {
                // change CGA plane (not relevant for decompression)
                // Assuming CGA plane change is already handled outside of decompression.
            } else if ((controlByte & 0x80) == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < controlByte; i++) {
                    short word;
                    if (!getNextTwoBytes(compressedData, position + i * 2, word)) {
                        std::cerr << "Error: Invalid input file format.\n";
                        return false;
                    }
                    decompressedData.insert(decompressedData.end(), {static_cast<char>(word & 0xFF), static_cast<char>(word >> 8)});
                }
                position += controlByte * 2;
            } else {
                controlByte = controlByte & 0x7F;
                short word;
                if (!getNextTwoBytes(compressedData, position, word)) {
                    std::cerr << "Error: Invalid input file format.\n";
                    return false;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < controlByte; i++) {
                    decompressedData.insert(decompressedData.end(), {static_cast<char>(word & 0xFF), static_cast<char>(word >> 8)});
                }
                position += 2;
            }
        }

        // Write the decompressed data to the output file using modern C++ iterators
        std::copy(decompressedData.begin(), decompressedData.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outputFile));
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    const std::string inputFilePath = "BACKS.bin";
    const std::string outputFilePath = "output_images.bin";

    if (extractAndDecompressImages(inputFilePath, outputFilePath)) {
        std::cout << "Extraction and decompression successful!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Extraction and decompression failed.n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Size of all compressed background images is stored in ARMORIK.COM at offset 0x67CB. Sizes are 2 bytes each.

As for help with your program, maybe it will be better to ask help at some place where CPP-programmers are answering questions (stackoverflow.com?)